# Ruby: Why does "and return" not return in this example?

Tags: ruby

```rb
def foo(x)
   puts "#{x} > 10" and return if x > 10
   puts "#{x} <= 10"
end
```

On the console:

```
> foo(3)
3 <= 10
> foo(30)
30 > 10
30 <= 10
```

Comment: change it to `return puts "#{x} > 10" if x > 10`, but it'd better to use `if else end` is this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Kernel#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) returns `nil`, which is *falsey*. `and` and `&&` only evaluate their right operand if they need to; since the left operand is already *falsey*, there is no need to evaluate the right operand.